# How does ffmpeg concatenate files that contain multiple streams with different codecs if codec=copy?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

This is a general question that is best explained by an example:

Suppose I have two M2TS files, `1.m2ts` and `2.m2ts`. Each file contains a video stream with 23.976 f/s (actually 24000/1001 f/s, frame duration 41.708 ms) and an E-AC3 audio stream with 31.25 f/s (frame duration 32 ms). In each file, the PTS of the first video frame is identical with the PTS of the first audio frame.

This means that generally the audio does not end at the same time as the video (unless in very rare random situations that occur with very low probability). To give the simplest example possible, let's assume that both files contain only one video frame; that frame's duration then is about 42 ms. Since an audio frame takes only 32 ms, there must be two audio frames in the file, because otherwise there would be silence at the end of the video frame.

So both files contain a video stream with a duration of 42 ms and an audio stream with a duration of 64 ms. What exactly happens if I let ffmpeg concatenate the files using `-codec copy`? Of course, I talk about the concat demuxer here, not the concat protocol:

File list.txt:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 1.m2ts
file 2.m2ts
```

Command line:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.m2ts
```

How does ffmpeg exactly deal with the different stream lengths in such situations?